# Image in upper left moved down toward center

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, eso-pic

I'm trying to insert an image at the upper left corner, and then move it down toward the center of the page. Similar questions lead me to try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{eso-pic} 
\usepackage{graphics}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\AtPageUpperLeft{\raisebox{-\height}{\hspace*{1cm}\vspace*{-1cm}
         \includegraphics[width=1.5in]{/Path/To/Image/animage.png}}}
}
\begin{document}
some words
\end{document}
```

It works for the horizontal shift, but not the vertical shift. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a point by yourself in the following manner:

```
\newcommand\AtPageUpperMyleft[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{1cm},\LenToUnit{-1cm}){#1}%
 }}%
```

Change `1cm` and `-1cm` as you wish.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
%% \usepackage{fullpage}  %% Use geometry instead
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\AtPageUpperMyleft[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{1cm},\LenToUnit{-1cm}){#1}%
 }}%
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
\AtPageUpperMyleft{\raisebox{-\height}{%
         \includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-a}}}
}
\begin{document}
some words
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another option with `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%% \usepackage{fullpage}  %% Use geometry instead
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \node[anchor=north west] at ([shift={(1cm,-1cm)}]current page.north
                  west){\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{example-image-a}};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
  }
\begin{document}
some words
\end{document}
```

Change the `shift={(1cm,-1cm)` as you wish. This takes atleast 2-3 compilation runs to settle down.

Comment: You can also use the `background` package if you wish.